# Microsoft exam Implementing a data warehouse

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse

I am going to give exam of microsoft 70-767 implementing a dwh
Can somebody advise me anything important related to exam or if anybody can provide me some practice test that will be really helpful
Thanx in advance

Comment: Did you try Googling `"70-767" "practice test"`?

Comment: Get the self paced training stuff and study

Comment: and now i want to take some test...

Answer (score 2):

The question you are asking is very vague or it can be answered relatively easily by using a search engine online. If you had a particular subject that you are having an issue wrapping your mind around or had some specific examples we could walk you through regarding a topic, you would get better feedback.

You can find the exam [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-767.aspx) and it covers EVERYTHING that is important and related to the exam. I would recommend to learn all of those topics listed in detail.

By default, the exam should not be the same or it could be the same, as someone elses. The point is to pick a number of questions regarding the topics to quiz you on to show overall proficiency in the category applied for the certification. The questions are in a mixed array of formatting, and you can find all of this information and more in the link I put above. This is supposed to show the individual understands the topics to the degree that they can be quizzed and could pass an examination of those topics. So if the individual were hired by your company, you could expect they have a reasonable amount of knowledge on that topic and can be seen as a resource to assist.

There is also an NDA associated to the exam, so even if I took the exam and wanted to tell you that you need to study "RANDOM TOPIC HERE" in depth because it is killer on the test, I would be violating that agreement. Your best bet is to know all of the material suggested very well.

Most certifications by Microsoft recommend one to two years of experience and they are supposed to be hard to pass. It's not to say you need experience or even knowledge to pass the exam, which is why there is some less weight applied to certs and why it can be a red flag if you see someone with a large quantity of certs in a variety of topics or a large quantity of certs over a short time.

Certifications should typically be more about the journey than the certification at the end. The cert is more of a show of achievement that you have passed that journey of education and learning the topics in detail to pass. It should take awhile, it should be hard, and it should cover a lot of information.

A lot of people find it beneficial to use the practice tests which are generally harder than the real test as it shows what topics you need more information on.

The practice exam can be found in the link I posted above or [here](http://www.mindhub.com/70-767-Developing-Implementing-a-Data-Warehouse-p/mu-70-767_p.htm) for easy viewing.

One last resource that is helpful for studying:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4741/exam-material-for-the-microsoft-70767--implementing-a-sql-data-warehouse/

Good luck.

Comment: I like the journey description